# Array_shift без сброса ключей

Tags: php

Нужно удалить первый элемент массива, не сбрасывая числовых ключей. Не могу сообразить как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`unset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php)

Код на [`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/6dFjm5)

Comment: http://ideone.com/nqqdQQ

Comment: В таких условиях не работает

Comment: @co11ter - [http://ideone.com/GNSFnu][1]

  [1]: http://ideone.com/GNSFnu

Comment: Спасибо.Объяснить поведение не сможете?

Comment: @co11ter - поведение чего именно? Уточните, пожалуйста, какие моменты не понятны - объясню.

Comment: Я разобрался. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
// устанавливаем указатель на первый элемент массива
reset($array)
// Удаляем его
unset($array[key($array)]);
```

Если никаких действий с указателем массива не производилось reset() можно пропустить.